# Listen to all events in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

I want to listen all the events that happen in my site.
I use the [monitorEvents()](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#monitoring_events) command, but this command only prints the event to the console, and I want to set a callback function for it to do some manipulations on that data without printing it to the console.

Is there any smart way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the best way to do it.
This code is based on the original [monitorEvents()](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events) command.
With this script its possible to listen all the Chrome events and handle them with custom function… you just need edit the "eventHandler" function.
For try it just copy to the Chrome console and then use: startMonitorEvents(window, eventHandler);

```
/**
* @param {Event} event
*/
function eventHandler(event)
{
    // Do whatever you want here... 

    console.log("my custom handler… ", event.type, event);
}

/**
* @param {Object} object
* @param {Function} callback
*/
function startMonitorEvents(object, callback)
{
    if (!object || !object.addEventListener || !object.removeEventListener)
                    return;
    var types = getEventsForMonitor();
    for (var i = 0; i < types.length; ++i) {
                    object.removeEventListener(types[i], callback, false);
                    object.addEventListener(types[i], callback, false);
    }
}

function getEventsForMonitor()
{
    var result = [];

    // mouse
    result.splice(0, 0, "mousedown", "mouseup", "click", "dblclick", "mousemove", "mouseover", "mouseout", "mousewheel");
    // key
    result.splice(0, 0, "keydown", "keyup", "keypress", "textInput");
    // touch
    result.splice(0, 0, "touchstart", "touchmove", "touchend", "touchcancel");
    // control
    result.splice(0, 0, "resize", "scroll", "zoom", "focus", "blur", "select", "change", "submit", "reset");
    // others
    result.splice(0, 0, "load", "unload", "abort", "error", "select", "change", "submit", "reset", "focus", "blur", "resize", "scroll", "search", "devicemotion", "deviceorientation");

    return result;
}

// Usage: startMonitorEvents(window, eventHandler);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
var eventsList = ["mousedown", "mouseup", "click", "dblclick", "mousemove",
    "mouseover", "mouseout", "mousewheel", "keydown", "keyup", "keypress", 
    "textInput", "touchstart", "touchmove", "touchend", "touchcancel", "resize",
    "scroll", "zoom", "focus", "blur", "select", "change", "submit", "reset"];

var callbackFunction = function(element, eventName) {
  console.log('Triggered event ' + eventName);
};

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('*');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < eventsList.length; j++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var event = eventsList[j];

    element.addEventListener(event,
        callbackFunction.bind(this, element, event), true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebug internally uses something like Paul Rad's solution, with the following list of events:

```
["DOMActivate", "DOMAttrModified", "DOMCharacterDataModified", "DOMFocusIn", "DOMFocusOut", "DOMNodeInserted", "DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument", "DOMNodeRemoved", "DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument", "DOMSubtreeModified", "abort", "beforeunload", "blur", "change", "click", "composition", "compositionend", "compositionstart", "contextmenu", "copy", "cut", "dblclick", "dragdrop", "dragenter", "dragexit", "draggesture", "dragover", "error", "focus", "input", "keydown", "keypress", "keyup", "load", "mousedown", "mousemove", "mouseout", "mouseover", "mouseup", "overflow", "overflowchanged", "paint", "paste", "reset", "resize", "scroll", "select", "submit", "text", "touchcancel", "touchend", "touchenter", "touchleave", "touchmove", "touchstart", "underflow", "unload"]
```